# convert KOI8-R xml node into unicode in c#

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding

I have the following xml:

```
<root>
   <text><![CDATA[ОПЕЛХМЮБЮ ОПЕГ БЗПРЪЫ ЯЕ АЮПЮАЮМ, Б ЙНИРН ЯЕ]]></text>
</root>
```

I know this text is generated using encoding KOI8-R (this text is displayed in my text editor only when I select this encoding when I open the xml file as text) and I would like to convert the value of this node into a string usable in c#. I can read the InnerText value of this node, but it's not what I'm expecting. Can someone show me the correct way to convert a string written with this encoding into a Unicode one?

**Update**

Following Jon Skeet suggestions, the solution would look like this:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("KOI8-R");
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();

using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(outputPath, encoding))
{
    doc2.Load(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How* do you have that XML? It should have an XML declaration stating which encoding it's using; otherwise it's not correct simply in XML terms. You shouldn't be worrying about encodings *after* you've parsed the XML. So potentially something like:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("KOI8-R");
XDocument doc;
using (var reader = File.OpenText("file.xml", encoding))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

... but as I say, the file itself should declare the encoding.

Comment: The file was generated by an external tool (xpdf - I think) and this is the only thing I got. Now, I am not quite familiar with linq and those external declarations ... what namespaces should I use to be allowed to specify the encoding for OpenText method? I tried with both System.Linq and System.Xml.Linq but none of them works ...

Comment: @dcg: If you don't want to use `XDocument`, then `XmlDocument.Load` will take a `TextReader` too. But it's pretty poor if xpdf is basically creating either an invalid XML file or one with the wrong text in. Are you sure it's not something which is going wrong earlier in the pipeline? It's worth finding out exactly where the problems start, otherwise you could easily be losing data.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way for me to go and change that thing. It's pretty old code written by someone else and it worked fine so far. It would be easier/faster for me just to take a look at the innerText value. Well, it works like this! Thanks!

Comment: @dcg: Just be aware that if the rest of the document *isn't* encoded using the same way, you could easily just be storing up problems for later. If this is something you'll be using long-term, I would serious consider investing the time in fixing the old code.